# Specific date and time range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have twelve events every day from 8am to 8pm every hour.

I have two columns in Excel spreadsheet: "date and time" and "description".

I need to add date and time stams for each cell of "date and time" column in the format

```
16/11/2011 08:00
```

So the first twelve cells will look like that:

```
16/11/2011 08:00
16/11/2011 09:00
16/11/2011 10:00
16/11/2011 11:00
16/11/2011 12:00
16/11/2011 13:00
16/11/2011 14:00
16/11/2011 15:00
16/11/2011 16:00
16/11/2011 17:00
16/11/2011 18:00
16/11/2011 19:00
16/11/2011 20:00
```

Then the next day shall come:

```
17/11/2011 08:00
17/11/2011 09:00
17/11/2011 10:00
17/11/2011 11:00
17/11/2011 12:00
17/11/2011 13:00
17/11/2011 14:00
17/11/2011 15:00
17/11/2011 16:00
17/11/2011 17:00
17/11/2011 18:00
17/11/2011 19:00
17/11/2011 20:00
```

Is there a way I can get the column filled in automatically for several months?

Comment: Your question is not very clear: just one time (I suggest use copy paste and you will be done faster than writing the question on SO) so I guess you need it to be repetitive with some kind of macro?

Comment: I have twelve events a day, so it's 4380 events a year. That's rather hard to copy / paste the date and time for each event. Yes, I need it to be repetitive.

Comment: Do you have any programming skills. If so, write a small programme in for example C# to create a CSV file and import that in Excel. Will not be a lot of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your first date in cell `A1`:

```
16/11/2011 08:00
```

And in cells `A2` and below, add the formula:

```
=A1+TIME(IF(HOUR(A1)=20,12,1),0,0)
```

and then drag down your formula till where you need.

[EDIT] Explaining a little bit the formula: in order to keep the formula quite simple, it is rather specific.
Meaningly,

- the formula starts at the previous date `A1 +`
- then, it adds some hours (with the `TIME` function) but no minutes nor seconds (`0,0)` i.e. see the end of the formula
- to choose the number of hours to add, it checks wether the previous date hour is `8pm` (i.e. `HOUR(A1) = 20`).

  - If so, it adds `12` hours so that the new date is at `8am` the next morning.
  - If not, it adds only `1` hour (next event)

[EDIT 2] New formula to skip week-ends (it checks wether the previous date is a friday (`WEEKDAY=6`) and hour is `8pm` (`HOUR(A1)=20`). If so, it adds two days (just add `2` because date in Excel are stored as serial number and unit is a day).

```
=A1+TIME(IF(HOUR(A1)=20,12,1),0,0) + IF(AND(HOUR(A1)=20,WEEKDAY(A1)=6),2,0)
```

Comment: I think your solution is close to perfect, but it gives me syntax error.

Comment: sorry, I've left some semi-colons `;` when I *internationalized* my formula. English version of Excel is using coma `,`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain the formula? what 20, 12, 1 actually mean? What if I would like to have 2-hour interval?

Comment: That's a great explanation. Is there a way we can skip weekends in the formula?

Comment: You are absolutely amazing! Thank you very much for sparing me a couple of hours of the monkey job.